# Set $_GET['foo'] variable when calling a PHP script on CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

When testing and developing some scripts, I would like to be able to define certain $_GET variables.

When a script is called trough mod_php/apache these variables will be defined by adding `?foo=bar` to the url.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Ask yourself why you are trying to use $_GET in a CLI program. Consider revising your design.

Comment: You are entirely right. It is just that firing the cli makes debugging and quick tests during development so much more easy then alt-tabbing to firefox for each and every change. In production GET will be used; in my development env I'd like a way to simply define some things there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Its not possible via CLI. However you can manually assign the value to the `$_GET` variable.

OR you can use the command line arguments and assign them to the `$_GET`.

```
$_GET['data'] = $argv;
```

^^That's a little bit manageable..

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `$_GET['foo'] = 'bar';` to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some code that is using $_GET['foo'] to do something then the best way to handle it would be to extract that code into a class/method/function and then have context-specific scaffolding which gathers the relevant data from the environment and passes it into the code-block to do it's stuff.

So let's say you had an inline PHP script like this:

```
$foo = $_GET['foo'];
// do what I need to do with $foo
```

Then you could wrap this into a function

```
function doBar( $foo ) {
    // do what I need to do with $foo
}
```

Your inline php script would now be

```
$foo = $_GET['foo'];
doBar( $foo );
```

And you could very easily write a CLI script to test this, either by setting $foo directly

```
$foo = 'test value';
doBar( $foo );
```

Or by parsing the CLI inputs and getting foo from there instead.

Basically, your code that does stuff (the Model in a traditional MVC) is isolated from its environment and can be used via an HTTP request, in a CLI script, in a unit test etc.

One thing I would stay clear of is assigning your own values to the $_GET and $_POST superglobals. It's smelly and a short-cut to giving you problems some way down the line.

Answer (score -1):

The two options to set $_GET variables: simply have something like:

```
 <a href='www.example.com/index.php?foo=bar'>blah</a>
```

This will set $_GET['foo'] to bar.

Or:

```
<form method='get' action='index.php'>
```

Any information you will send with this form will be retrievable with $_GET.

Comment: Neither of which is at all applicable to the CLI.